# New bitcoin source compile failure

Tags: bitcoin

So I trying compile current litecoin source, that is basically same with bitcoin newest source.

> ./autogen.sh
>
> ./configure
>
> make
>
> sudo make install

These 4 line should be executed linearly? 
When I did type "make", very long process gone, and lastly error says,

> Makefile:9357: recipe for target 'all-recursive' failed. make : ***
>   [all-recursive] error 1

and I did type "make install" but same errors.

So eventually ./mycoind  does not produced Debug.Log file at ubuntu OS's [Home/.mycoin] folder.

Why am I getting these errors and how do I fix it?

Comment: There should be more error messages before that. Try to understand what those say.

Comment: uploaded error image  http://naver.me/55BHuWIC

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Try to build using make (without install) and use the -i flag to see what could be the possible error for build to fail as this flag will ignore errors and keep continuing the build process.

```
make -i
```

After resolving those issues start build from database again

```
cd db-4.8.30.NC/build_unix    
../dist/configure --enable-cxx --disable-shared --with-pic --prefix=/home/ubuntu/Desktop/BitcoinEssence/db4
make install
```

Then cd to BitcoinEssence folder and run the following commands again

```
./autogen.sh
./configure --enable-debug --enable-werror LDFLAGS="-L/home/ubuntu/Desktop/BitcoinEssence/db4/lib/" CPPFLAGS="-I/home/ubuntu/Desktop/BitcoinEssence/include/"
 make - i
./src/bitcoinessenced
```

Also, there is no need to run
    `make install`
after running
    `make`